# Images in loop with different div class in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, loops

Suppose I have code like bellow

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo '<div class="single">';
    echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].' " />';
    echo '</div>';
} 
?>
```

And I want to append `first` and `last` in div class `<div class="single">` in every set of 5 images i.e

```
<div class="single first">
    <img src="image1.jpg" alt="title1" />
</div>

<div class="single">
    <img src="image2.jpg" alt="title2" />
</div>

<div class="single">
    <img src="image3.jpg" alt="title3" />
</div>

<div class="single">
    <img src="image4.jpg" alt="title4" />
</div>

<div class="single last">
    <img src="image5.jpg" alt="title5" />
</div>
```

How to do it through loop, please help,

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 0;
$class = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    if($i % 5 == 0){
        $class = 'first';
    }else if($i % 5 == 4){
        $class = 'last';
    }else{
        $class = "";
    }

    echo '<div class="single ' . $class . '">';
    echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].' " />';
    echo '</div>';

    $i++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: You have a typo at `$clas = 'last';` and you'll need to add a space after `class="single'` otherwise the classes are running together (e.g. `class="singlelast"`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it couldn't display `class = "single last"` please help

Comment: See my edit - to check for "last", you need to check if `$i % 5 == 4`  instead of `== -1` - PHP is not good at algebra :/

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$x=0; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $x++;
    if ( $x == 1 ) { $c = ' first'; } 
        elseif ( $x == 5 ) { $c = ' last'; }
        else { $c = ''; }

    echo '<div class="single' . $c . '">';
    echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].' " />';
    echo '</div>';
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not displaying `class = "single first"`

Comment: Right you are! I've updated the code, but it looks like you've already got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $classes = 'single';
    switch ($index % 5) {
      case 0:
        $classes .= ' first';
        break;
      case 4:
        $classes .= ' last';            
        break;
    }
    echo <<<HTML
<div class="$classes">
  <img src="{$row['image']}" alt="{$row['title']}" />
</div>;
HTML;

    $index++;
}
```

As a sidenote, have you considered using CSS `nth-child` property instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need to count your iterations, and use the modulo function to get parts of 5:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if($i % 5 == 0)
      echo '<div class="single first">';
    else if($i % 5 == 4) 
      echo '<div class="single last">';
    else
      echo '<div class="single">';
    echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].' " />';
    echo '</div>';
    $i++;
}
```